# Paperclip default url image isn't working in Rails 5

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, sprockets

I am using Paperclip for image upload processing. I am trying to show default image when there is no image uploaded by User. Here is my code for `default_url` option :

```
  has_attached_file :logo,
                    :styles => { square: "200x200>", small: "400x400>", profile: "240x175>" },
                    :default_url => ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path('folder1/logo/:style/default.jpg')
```

Here is my code for how I am rendering image :

`@my_model_instance.logo.url`

My image path in project is `app/assets/images/folder1/logo/original/default.jpg`

I have googled it but no luck. Default image is still not rendered on page.

Any help will be appriciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`ActionController::Base.helpers.asset_path('folder1/logo/:style/default.jpg')` is equal to `"/assets/folder1/logo/:style/default.jpg"` by default. 
It would work if the file were in `app/assets/images/assets/folder1/logo/:style/default.jpg` directory.

You don't have to use `asset_path` method here. Just specify a relative path

```
has_attached_file :logo,
                  :default_url => '/folder1/logo/:style/default.jpg'
```

Then the default image url will be `/assets/folder1/logo/:style/default.jpg` and the file will be found in the folder you put it into.

Comment: Thank you chumakoff. I will try today and let you know.